# Initializing std::shared_ptr with std::make_shared having an std::array as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr

I do not understand why this works fine:

```
std::array<double, 2> someArray = {0,1};
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myobj = std::make_shared<MyClass>(someArray);
```

But this does not work:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myobj = std::make_shared<MyClass>({0,1});
```

Compiler says:

```
too many arguments to function ‘std::shared_ptr< _Tp> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...)
...
candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

**Question:** Can someone clarify why this happens and if there is any way I can fix the second approach without defining an extra variable?

---

**Edit:**
Example of `MyClass`:

```
#include <memory> //For std::shared_ptr
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass{
  public:
    MyClass(std::array<double, 2> ){
      std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
    };
};
```

Comment: What is MyClass?

Comment: ... and what does its constructors look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Braced initializers `{}` can never be deduced to a type (in a template context). A special case is `auto`, where it is deduced to `std::initializer_list`. You always have to explictly define the type.

```
auto myobj = std::make_shared<MyClass>(std::array<double, 2>{0, 1});
```

Comment: `auto myobj = std::make_shared<MyClass>(std::array{0., 1.});` would be fine too.

Answer (score -1):

The type of `{0, 0}` is context-dependent. If `{0, 0}` is being used to immediately construct another object of known type, then it represents a `prvalue` of that object type:

```
MyClass m({0, 0});
```

Here, `{0, 0}` refers to a prvalue of type `std::array<double, 2>`
On the other hand, if there are no constraints on the type, then `{0, 0}` refers to an initializer list of type `std::initializer_list<int>`:

```
auto vals = {0, 0};
```

There's no way to initialize `MyClass` from `std::initializer_list<int>`, so `make_shared` fails to compile:

```
MyClass m(vals); // Fails: can't construct MyClass from initializer list
```

**How does this connect to `std::make_shared`?** Because `std::make_shared` is a template, `{0, 0}` isn't being used to construct a specific type. As a result, it's treated as a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: This is not correct.  `{0, 0}` is only a `std::initializer_list<int>` when used with `auto`.  Without **it has no type**

Comment: Isn’t it also a std::initiaizer_list when passed to a templated function?

Comment: No.  A special rule was added for `auto` so it could work (still not sure if I like that or not).  No rule was put in place for template deduction.